# Body laser hair removal

Tags: hair, shaving

I'm asking specifically for body hair removal by laser.

I'm not talking about armpit hair, but rather chest and stomach hair.

Is there any problem with it?

Comment: related - if not duplicate - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/removing-facial-hair-by-laser-treatment-for-a-man and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16453/can-a-man-remove-hair

Comment: What Halachic problem is there with using a razor on those parts?