# Shaving pubic hair during sefira

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, shaving

Are men and women permitted to shave pubic hair during sefira?

(Obviously only regarding a situation in that it is already permitted for the subject to shave his/her pubic hair during the year)

Comment: Men are not permitted, by most authorities, to shave pubic hair - year-round. Sorry, I don't remember the sources, maybe a Rabbi here could point them out for us.

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30299/is-it-permitted-for-a-male-to-shave-his-pubic-hair-nowadays for the answer to that problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule applies to hair anywhere on the body ([*Nit'e Gavriel*, *Pesach* volume 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/46449), chapter 49, paragraph 2, page 279; see that chapter for exceptions, but pubic hair is explicitly not excepted).

Answer (score 1):

Sephardic authorities such as Rav Ovadia Yoseph require women to shave their pubic hair prior to immersing in the mikvah. A woman who follows this practice may certainly shave her pubic hair if she needs to go to the mikvah during sephirah.

The prohibition of a man shaving his pubic hair derives from the assumption of Chazal that shaving pubic hair is the way of women and for a man it is prohibited from the pasuk (Devarim 22:5) "Lo yilbash gever simlas isha" "A man may not wear female clothes". Rashi there gives two explanations, the second of which is that a man must not remove his pubic or underarm hair. The word he uses is not shave, it is lo yasir, do not remove. So whereas a depilatory is permissible for a man to use to remove his beard (and vastly preferable halachically to using a shaver), seemingly he should not use it to remove underarm or pubic hair.

Comment: Can you cite where R Yoseph rules this way? Why would a woman who follows this practice "certainly" be allowed to shave? Can you source that Rashi's choice of words in this regard has that connotation, that we rule in accordance with Rashi's opinion, and that that rule is still in force in today's culture? Can you address if Sefira restrictions would still be in place above the cited prohibition? Note that the question assumed the case would be one where it would be otherwise permitted to shave pubic hair.