# Jewish hats throughout the ages

Tags: history, black-hats, hats

Is there a book or any other source which goes through the history of which types of hats jews wore throughout history?
Also, regarding the Ashkenazi minhag to wear the fedora - why is it worn with the brim bent up, as opposed to what I assume to be correct, bent down?

Comment: "The ages" go back a long way. Until the last century or so it was pretty much just whatever hats everyone else wore

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/61bIQ6F

Comment: https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/7433-head-dress

Comment: Many wear the fedora brim down.

Comment: Regarding Fedoras https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51322/how-and-when-did-fedoras-arise-as-acceptable-headwear