# Open blade razor on areas other than face and peyot

Tags: hair

Can an open blade razor be used to remove hair on areas other than the face and peyot?
For example, a barber using an open blade on the back of the neck? Additionally a razor to remove pubic hairs?

Comment: why do you think there would be an issue? the issur is only for the five points of the beard, which no opinion puts anywhere close to the back of the neck

Comment: @ezra, removing pubic hair might be a violation of beged ishah, according to some opinions though

Comment: relevant: [Is it permitted for a male to shave his pubic hair nowadays?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30299/11501)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt not all opinions agree that shaving pubic hair is a violation of beged isha, especially nowadays in most western societies

Comment: @ezra Why "especially" and not "only"? Does anyone disagree about prior generations?

Comment: @DoubleAA in previous generations even in the west it wasn't always common for a man to trim "down there", since the halacha bases itself on the surrounding culture that would be an important detail. today i would say it's very common for a man to trim his body hair

Comment: @ezra that doesn't address my question. You said especially but you should have said only.

Comment: @DoubleAA no that would make it the opposite of what i'm saying! im saying especially in western countries where it's common for people to shave their body hair there is no issue to. please reread my comment i said NOT all opinions etc

Comment: @ezra not especially. Only. Only nowadays is it permitted. The rule is it's prohibited except [arguably] where there's a local custom permitting it. Why would it be permitted otherwise that you say that especially in modern western countries it is permitted?

Comment: Read it this: not all opinions agree that shaving pubic hair is a violation of beged isha, especially in western societies they agree it is not a violation

Comment: @ezra yes that's exactly what I'm critiquing.  You should say: not all opinions agree that shaving pubic hair is a violation of beged isha, only in western societies. Or alternatively: all agree it's a violation, except some opinions permit in modern western societies where it's common