# Plucking Hair For Men

Tags: halacha, beard

Is it mutar for a man to pluck his beard hair with his hands or does this fall under the issur of destroying the corners of the face?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8290/1362 resources http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8290/1362 and resolution http://dinonline.org/2015/05/15/plucking-facial-hair/

Comment: What about when a man accidentally plucks hairs from his beard due to stroking it? This happens frequently with most people I know.

Answer (score 1):

Many Orthodox Jews, including Hasidism, refrain from cutting their beards altogether, and, with the exception of occasionally trimming their mustaches when they interfere with eating, never cut their facial hair. Those Orthodox Jews who do shave their facial hair must utilize electric shavers as opposed to razors.

To your question if plucking falls under the Issur of destroying the corners of the face, as long it is not done with a razor, Issur does not apply. 
The Mishnah interprets this as a prohibition on using a razor on the beard. See Eidut L'Yisrael P. 145

You may want to check out [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16453/can-a-man-remove-hair) if removing hair from a man's body falls under the Issur of "**Lo Tilbash**".

Comment: Hi Moses. We don't know you so we have no reason to trust the claims you make, particularly the one in the last sentence (which is the only one that addresses the question). Please [edit] in sources for them.

Answer (score 0):

The credit here goes completely to Danno who linked this psak, but for the sake of answering the question here: http://dinonline.org/2015/05/15/plucking-facial-hair/

Plucking facial hair in a way commonly done by men as well as women is permitted. It is forbidden for a man to pluck out white hair from a colored beard [Y:D 182:6]. Plucking hair from the sideburns should be avoided as according to some opinions this is a problem of הקפת הראש, removing sideburns. See Gilyon Hashas Shavuos 2b, and Shu”t Chasam Sofer Y:D 139.