# Is scissors vs. straight blade really a significant difference?

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, shaving, leniencies

While listening to a presentation being given by an orthodox Jew, he made a comment about shaving, and how he had to use an electric razor past a certain point on his face.  It was just a conversational, in-passing remark during introductions for a meeting that had nothing to do with Judaism, so I didn't get a chance to ask about it.  But I am curious...

I am not Jewish, but customs regarding hair are common in Christian and Muslim sects as well, so I totally get that part.  [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaving_in_Judaism) and [this SE question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87469/why-is-shaving-with-a-regular-razor-not-allowed) both do a good job of explaining where the custom comes from.

The distinction comes down to the use of a straight blade vs. a pair of scissors, but this argument doesn't make sense to me in our modern technological age.

If the *religious* objective is that you should not destroy the corners of the head and of the beard, how does an electric razor -- which accomplishes very nearly the same exact thing as a straight razor does -- be acceptable to that objective?  It seems like splitting hairs to me (pun very much intended).

BTW, the guy giving the presentation was clean-shaven.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Wes

Comment: @mbloch; Thanks :-). I referenced that question but it doesn't contain the info I'm looking for. It only explains that scissors are OK because of two blades coming together rather than a single blade, but I already understand that.

Comment: What if the religious objection is to using a straight blade vs a pair of scissors?

Comment: @DoubleAA; I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you not assume something else is the religious objection such that you have your question?

Comment: "which accomplishes _very nearly_ the same exact thing" (your quote, emphasis mine). This does imply that you concede that there is a difference. The simple answer would be that whatever this difference is, that's enough of a distinction to remove it from the prohibition against shaving.

Comment: Since we don't have a conclusive answer about WHY G-d would prohibit shaving certain parts of the beard and temples, how can you know what is a significant difference and what is not?